# In a spaceship, if a vessel suddently stops will an object inside the vessel keep going?

Tags: gravity, space, inertia

My question is a 2 part question.

First if a vessel in space is going very fast and suddently stops (maybe it is not possible but that is not the point) will things/humans inside the vessel keep going forward or stop with the vessel?

Is it the same if the cabin is oxygened or not?

I know the question is pretty vague but please explain possibilities.

Comment: This happens in moving vehicles on Earth, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> going very fast and suddently stops (maybe it is not possible but that is not the point)

Well, *"stops"* isn't actually well defined, but if it is subject to a thrust "backwards" any unsecured contents will all bang up against the "forward" bulkheads.

So, the answer is to your first part is **yes**.

Now, if there is an atmosphere present that will *also* slosh forward, but since it is a gas this will have no appreciable effect unless you have a helium baloon along--that will float toward the back of the vessel because buoyancy goes against the local effective gravity--or things get up to enough speed to encounter significant air resistance.

So the answer to your second part is **mostly yes, things will still move forward with some specific exceptions**.

Answer (score 7):

Yes the things/humans inside the vessel will keep going forward due to inertia.
Since the things/humans have kinetic energy due to motion, they would keep moving.

Whether the cabin is oxygened is not important: If you are comparing between a vessel filled with oxygen (or some other gas) and a vacuum vessel, the difference would be that the things/humans inside the vessel would encounter air resistance in the vessel filled with oxygen (or some other gas). Due to the air resistance, the things/humans would slow down (the slow down is insignificant if you have a long time frame)/